# Parse won't save objects in local datastore after I close application and disconnect from Wi-Fi

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, parse-platform, offline-caching

I'm trying to save some objects locally so when I close my application and disconnect from my Wi-Fi I'll still be able to have the data but this does not work.
I have created this function to save my database.

```
func saveAllQueriesLocally() {
        let queries = PFQuery(className: "Directory")
        PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackground()
        queries.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // The query failed
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let object = object {
                
                // The query succeeded with a matching result
                for i in object{
                    i.pinInBackground()
                }
                
            } else {
                // The query succeeded but no matching result was found
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have called this function inside viewDidLoad() of my main ViewController. I am not sure but I am guessing the function searches the database when it is offline and since it does not retrieve anything it rewrites the cache as empty.
While being connected to the internet, objects get retrieved correctly.

Comment: Have you tried the saveEventually function? http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#saving-objects-offline

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Well, apparently it was that easy, thank you!